# Autoclicker speed inaccuracies result in weird test results?

Tags: c++, windows, math, winapi, timer

While coding my own auto clicker I noticed an extreme inaccuracy with the click speed. When nothing I tried worked, I downloaded more auto clickers. I saw that every auto clicker I tested has extremely inaccurate CPS outputs, including mine. The inaccuracy scales in a weird way when the CPS input is increased.

I confirmed that my click speed tester works correctly by using different ones. I also tried two different ways of sleeping: CreateWritableTimer(Graph 1); Sleep(Graph 2).
Here are my test results: (Bumps in the graph are due to inaccuracies)

This is Graph 1:
[image: Graph 1]

This is Graph 2:
[image: Graph 2]

Here is my Autoclicker thread:

```
std::atomic<bool> AutoClicker::AutoClickerActive;

void AutoClicker::AutoClickThread(int Speed, bool CPS) // Speed is either the intervall in ms or the clicks per second, depending on the CPS bool
{
    long long SleepTime_ns;
    if (CPS == true)
        SleepTime_ns = (1.0 / Speed) * 1000; // Variable name incorrect because I changed it to ms for the Sleep() demonstration
    else
        SleepTime_ns = Speed;

    INPUT Inputs[2];
    ZeroMemory(&Inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
    Inputs[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Inputs[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    Inputs[0].mi.time = 0;
    Inputs[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Inputs[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    Inputs[1].mi.time = 0;

    while (AutoClickerActive.load() == true) 
    {
        // Get current cursor position
        //POINT cursorPos;
        //GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
        //Inputs[0].mi.dx = cursorPos.x;
        //Inputs[0].mi.dy = cursorPos.y;

        SendInput(2, Inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
        Sleep(SleepTime_ns); // Not used normally
        //Utils::nanosleep(SleepTime_ns); // Used normally
    }
}
```

Utils::nanosleep() function:

```
BOOLEAN Utils::nanosleep(LONGLONG ns)
{
    HANDLE timer;
    LARGE_INTEGER li;   /* Time defintion */

    if (!(timer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL)))
        return FALSE;

    /* Set timer properties */
    li.QuadPart = -ns;
    if (!SetWaitableTimer(timer, &li, 0, NULL, NULL, FALSE)) {
        CloseHandle(timer);
        return FALSE;
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(timer, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(timer);
    return TRUE;
}
```

My question is: How would I calculate the "Input CPS" needed to reach the desired measurement? The CreateWritableTimer() output graph looks more consistent and like a mathematical function.

Comment: Any `sleep` has some accuracy. don't you reach them?

Comment: When you have the choice between renaming a variable to match, and leaving a comment why the variable name is misleading, there's only one correct response.

Comment: `Sleep` usually has a pretty coarse resolution, and the process wakes up "at some point of time, at the operating system's discretion" after the given time period. I think you might get better graphs if you look at milliseconds per click instead of clicks per second. (I think the other one asymptotically converges to ~16 ms plus signal-and-wait overhead.)